# Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: fibonacci

So i am supposed to add all the odd Fibonacci Numbers and return the sum. Here is my code but i am not getting it right. Sorry i am new at this so help me out.

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  let secpre=0
  let pre=1
  let current=0;
  let arr=[pre]
  let y=[]
  let sum
  for(let i=1;i<=num;i++){
if(num==1){return 1}
    else if((secpre+pre)<num){
      current=secpre+pre;
      secpre=pre;
      pre=current;
     arr.push(current)

    }  
  }

arr.map(x=>{if(x%2!==0){
  return y.push(x)
}})

y.reduce((a,b)=>{ sum=0;
sum+=a+b;
return sum
})

console.log(y)
console.log(sum)
return sum

  }
```

sumFibs(75025)

for the value of sumFibs(75025), it should be 135721 but i am getting 60696.

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using.

Comment: JavaScript, @chepner.

Comment: Thanx Hcaertnit. Sorry I forgot to add

Answer (score 1):

You've had a nice idea, well done! Although, here is the solution for which I think is simpler to understand:

```
    function sumFib(num) {
       let odd_sum = 1;
       let nums = [0, 1];
       while (odd_sum < num) {
           new_num = nums[nums.length - 2] + nums[nums.length - 1];
           nums.push(new_num);
           if (new_num % 2 == 1) odd_sum += new_num;
       }
       return odd_sum;
   }
   console.log(sumFib(75025));
```

Feel free to ask if you are confused with something.